# Twitter embedded making content drop

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm currently writing a site which requires a basic twitter embedded widget. I have put the widget in the `<aside>` tag which is being placed to the right of the main `<article>`. The widget forces my article tag further down the page than it should be, and I don't understand why, can anybody enlighten me?

Html:

```
   <article>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </article>

    <aside>
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/LydbrookAth" data-widget-id="690232327222509569">  </a>
        <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>      
    </aside>
```

Css:

```
article {
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: dashed;
    height: 600px;

}

aside {
    width: 28%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: dashed;
    height:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to the `article` to give it a specific alignment.